# Trying to gain access to object's property defined by myself

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox that I need to add a Tag to every item. So I do it with this code:

```
 public class ListBoxItem : Object
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Tag { get; set; }

    public ListBoxItem()
    {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.Tag = 0;
    }
    public ListBoxItem(string Text, int Tag, int Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Text = Text;
        this.Tag = Tag;

    }
    public ListBoxItem(object Object)
    {
        this.Text = Object.ToString();

    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

I add an item corectly when I need after giving it a Tag, over here it is OK.
But when I try to browse my listbox i can't accede to Tag:

```
for (int i=0; i< listBox_map.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listBox_map.Items[i].Tag==1) // .Tag don't appeare
              //do something
        }
```

This is my problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the list item which is of type Object to your type , like this :

```
if ((listBox_map.Items[i] as ListBoxItem).Tag==1)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I really thank you Gortler! i know i have to cast it but i can't find the wright way.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you aren't checking for null when you do "as" then you might as well just directly cast it. This will throw an object reference exception instead of an invalid cast exception which is a bit clearer identifying the problem when debugging :)